# Telling Eclipse to use a different JDBC driver in an already built project?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

So basically what I'm being told to do is try to run an already finished product with a newer JDBC driver and see if it works/causes any problems.

I already tried adding the jar to the build path in which the old jar was located and removed the older from the build path, but then I got errors in other parts of the code.

Does that mean the new driver doesn't work? Because I don't know how else you would specify to use that exact driver.

I checked if you could somehow alter the element in *persistance.xml* so it takes the path of the driver in consideration, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: By new driver you mean the newer version of driver from the same vendor or a new driver from different vendor?

Comment: @user2004685 same vendor

Comment: Sounds like your project depends on internal classes of the driver (which might have changed between versions) and not the JDBC API. But without examples of the code and the exact errors, there is not much we can do to help.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That was the reason, but not because classes changed during versions but me taking the wrong .jar in the first place, whoops.